# Apache2.4 strange ServerAlias wildcard behavior

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, wildcard, serveralias

I'm trying to create wildcard virtualhosts with ServerAliases

- sub.*.tld
- sub.*.tld2
- *.tld
- *.tld2

(loaded in that order), the ones without the subdomain obviously work, but the first two do not, falling back to the default domain.
I couldn't find any specific reference in the apache web server docs regarding the wildcard behavior so I'm assuming it is possible since it is in shell globbing. Does * only match on the beginning / end of the string? Couldn't find any reference of this.

If not possible, how could I circumvent this limitation?